# Should non changing content be in index.html or the top level app.vue file

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Noob question sorry

I'm following along some YouTube courses and learning Vue, and am in the process of creating my own Vue components.

In certain parts of my page there will be Vue components, but should the rest of the html code (page structure, header/footer) etc go inside the index.html file (with a linked style sheet), or should it go in the app.vue < template > tags, with all the style content in the < style > tags?

Comment: It's really up to you but you might find it easier to make changes later on if all your application layout is within Vue components.

Comment: Just to confirm, if it's all in .vue files, you don't have a default css file that way? Everything would be in the < style > tag inside the .vue file? Thanks

Comment: Again, that's completely up to you. There's nothing stopping you including a `<link>` tag in your `index.html` file. That's usually where I put Google fonts for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make Components for Navbar/Footer, and then insert them in your App.vue so they are Always there, then you still have the Option to make some of the Content dynamic, but you dont have to.

Basicly something like this as a Page structure is recommended if you want a Navbar or a Footer.

App.vue

> Import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue'
>
> Import Footer from '@/components/Footer.vue'

```
 <Navbar></Navbar>
```

Your other Content w/e your Page might look like

```
 <Footer></Footer>
```